# When to Call Something "Docs" and When to Call it "Drive"

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

So, a quick background.  I make productivity apps (specifically CRM and Project Management).  And I love the docs, spreadsheet and presentation products made by Google.  Not surprisingly, my products have done a lot of "things" with Google Docs for a long time:

- Create "native" (ie. Docs/Spreadsheets/Presentations) documents
- Use native documents as templates
- Link and modify permissions of any file in Docs/Drive
- Upload any arbitrary file
- etc.

What I'm confused about is what does Google want me to do on the labels on the buttons in my app.  Right now, they all say "Google Docs".  You're linking any arbitrary file to a presentation, you're linking it from "Google Docs".  You're exporting a spreadsheet of time sheet entries, you're exporting it to "Google Docs".  You upload a PDF, you uploaded it to Google Docs. Etc.

What I'm confused about is that, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it is a complete switch over to "Drive."  I still see labels on the Google site for Google Docs.  So, this is what I think the breakdown is:

If it is a Google "native" file, then it is Docs, else it is Drive.  Thus, if your uploading any arbitrary file, that button should refer to drive.  But if you are exporting a spreadsheet of data to the Google Spreadsheets format, then that is Docs.

Is this right at all?  Does Google have some information somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: personal opinion

I would use Drive everywhere, except when specifically talking about the collaborative word processor provided in Google Drive, that is the Google Doc.

I would also make sure that all my integrations use the new [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive).

Answer (score 2):

There is reasonably good guidance here: https://developers.google.com/drive/branding

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs and Google Drive are two seperate products from Google. They can work together, but they are still their own individual products and should be called their respective names when being used